# Maintaining two different versions of a record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table which has the following columns:

```
Id, HeaderText, ContentText, ProposedContentId, Active
```

I want to maintain two versions of records that are edited by users using a website. For example, user John could edit the **HeaderText** and **ContentText** fields of the following record and click save.

```
    Id,    HeaderText,    ContentText,    ProposedContentId, Active
==> 1,    Hello,          This is a test,    NULL,             1
```

But instead of updating that same record I want to create another record and point from the old record to new record. Now the table looks like this:

```
     Id, HeaderText,    ContentText,         ProposedContentId, Active
     1, Hello,          This is a test,           2,              0
 ==> 2, Hello World,    This is a new post,      NULL,            1
```

As you can see, the old record is marked as not **active** and now the **ProposedContentId** points to the newly created row.

I don't know whether this is good solution to this problem. Please suggest better ways if there are any.

**Edit**: I only need to maintain two copies (old and new) and I cannot create extra tables.

Comment: you probably want to incorporate foreign keys/shared keys into your solution to take advantage of your server's native optimizations. Can't outsmart your server. So to elaborate have one identifier that all these posts would share and then perhaps an ordering or 'current' marker as another column.

Comment: The Id field is a PK and the ProposedContentId field is guaranteed to be unique. I thought that would suffice.

Comment: I am thinking to later when it could get difficult for you to find which entries go together. I assume there will be many header texts and content texts or is this table just for 1 entry that will be continuously modified? It sounded like there would be many records stored in this table, and I don't see an easy way to group them together right now since they have different Id, ProposedContentID. How would you quickly find all the related posts?

Comment: you can create two tables one primary table having the active records and one history table/Secondary table which get populated using trigger... and if you want to see both active and inactive create a view which does a union between the two and gives you result set.

Comment: Instead of `ProposedContentId` ,keep a column called `OriginalPostId`, and populate it in the new rows (second, third and so on). this should keep the Id of the first row in all later rows, while in the first row it should be null. This way you can easily tell what row belongs where.

Comment: @sunny Initially the table will only have 1 copy of each row. But when a user modifies a row, we need to keep the old copy and new copy, so we can go back and revert if need be. We need exactly 2 versions after a row has been changed.

Comment: I recall supporting an app that had a database structure similar to this, maintaining multiple revisions of a record, and it was an unmitigated nightmare to maintain in the real world. Tread cautiously.

Comment: @hyde the operative but missing word in what you say is "for now"...

Comment: [This method](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-strategies-for-versioned-data/) strikes me as much easier to maintain and support in the long run.  Separating the version metadata and the record (document) data does seem to have some benefits.

Comment: "I cannot create extra tables" sounds restrictive to me. Your current solution could effect performance. To display post #1, you have to go Id 1, if it's not active , you have to check the #2, and ..... what happen if you have 100+ versions? I suggest you have a new posts table, storing the postID and the versioned id which pointing the active version. So the postId will not change but you can store any number of versions for it.

Comment: @Tim3880. I only need to maintain two copies.

Comment: If you only ever need two copies, then you only need the proposedContentId. If it's null you know it's the active record.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not use this `Active` flag as a way of tracking the latest record. This type of identifier gets tricky to maintain.

I would add a content identifier to your table. Then, when a record gets changed, simply insert the new data with the same content identifier. The `Id` field will auto increment, or you could add a datetime field, then you can track the active record by looking at record the highest Id (or latest timestamp) for that given `ContentId`.

```
Id,   ContentId   HeaderText       ContentText          
1     1           Hello            This is a test        
2     1           Hello World      This is a new post    
3     1           Hello again!     The content was changed again
4     2           New Content      This is some new text  
5     2           Newer Content    This is that other record, updated
```

You could add in an active flag to this setup if you want, but it doesn't really have to be any more complex than each record having it's own identifier like a `ContentId` and knowing the active record by whatever has the highest ID, or latest timestamp. However you'd prefer to do it.

If you wanted to get the "active" records, all you'd need to do is run something like this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
JOIN (
SELECT ContentId, MAX(Id) MaxId FROM YourTable GROUP BY ContentId) B
ON A.ContentId = B.ContentId AND A.Id = B.MaxId
```

That should give you the following:

```
Id,   ContentId   HeaderText       ContentText          
3     1           Hello again!     The content was changed again
5     2           Newer Content    This is that other record, updated
```

I hope this helps or at least gives you some food for thought.